# \entry has an extra }

Tags: cv, friggeri-cv

```
Argument of \entry has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.145 {DaPulse}
                – Project Management\newline
```

I am new to Latex and trying to add a simple list of other qualifications to my CV, but I keep getting this error.

Here is my code for other qualifications:

```
%   OTHER QUALIFICATIONS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{other qualifications}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{MS Office:}
MS Word – Editing
MS Excel – Graphs, Formulas, Tables
MS PowerPoint\newline
\entry
{CRM – Exai}\newline
\entry
{DaPulse} – Project Management\newline
\entry
{HTML} comprehension\newline
\entry
{WIX} – Creating and Editing Website Content
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}
```

Where do I put the brackets in order to make a list?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example document that reproduces the problem. Without this (and so lacking information about the document class, macros you have defined, packages you use, etc.) it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. A `cventry` takes four mandatory arguments. It is designed to take a year, and a title and a description.

What i think you are looking for, is just a small and simple table. Keep it simple, don't let a template decide what you want to do.

[image: texsxFriggeriEntry]

The list as defined by the template is in the middle, a simple table  with the information you want to give is at the bottom. The top of the image shows the general design of the template.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Friggeri Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (3/5/15)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Adrien Friggeri (adrien@friggeri.net)
% https://github.com/afriggeri/CV
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important notes:
% This template needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX and the bibliography, if used,
% needs to be compiled with biber rather than bibtex.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing
\usepackage{mwepage}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} } JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}
\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2007--2008}
{Bachelor {\normalfont of Business Studies}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{Specialization in Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry{MS Office:}{MS Word – Editing,
    MS Excel – Graphs, Formulas, Tab,
    MS PowerPoint}{}{}
\entry{CRM – Exai}{}{}{}
\entry{DaPulse}{Project Management}{}{}
\entry{HTML}{comprehension}{}{}
\entry{WIX}{Creating and Editing Website Content}{}{}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\quad}l}
MS Office  & MS Word – Editing, MS Excel – Graphs, Formulas, Tab, MS PowerPoint\\
CRM-Exai &\\
DaPulse    & Project Management\\
HTML       & comprehension\\
WIX        & Creating and Editing Website Content
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```